# How to pass a POST request to the router pages in Express?

Tags: node.js, express

I am receiving a POST request in the app.js file using `app.post('/index',function(req,res){
//some code})`.
How can I pass the request to one of my router pages (index.js)?

My index.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: will you provide the skeleton of index.js?

Comment: I added it, but it's just the basic router file.

Comment: If I've understood your question correctly. The answer is added. Clarification, you dont want your .post to be redirected to the .get function?

Comment: I want the .get and .post to be handled seperately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your app.js you have to connect the `Router` to your application. This is an example of how to do that.

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./index.js');

var app = express();
app.use(routes);
app.listen(1337);
```

**index.js**

```
var router = require('express')();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

router.post('/index', function(req, res) {
  // Your code here
});

module.exports = router;
```

This will tell your app to include the middleware of the `Router`.

Comment: This is already done by the express generator. To be more specific, I have a submit button which uses a POST method. When clicked, the request goes into the app.js file with the ````app.post(url,function)```` I would like to handle this request in the files which are kept in /router/.

Your answer tells me how to handle get requests. I'm looking to send a post request to the router.
I hope this makes it clearer. Thanks

Comment: Just add a new endpoint to the router in the file you wish to have it.

Comment: There is no router.post method which causes an unresolved function error.

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router for details on the `Router`. Though you dont have to use it. You could just use the express base functionality aswell. Let me update my answer to show how

Comment: I skimmed the docs which said router.METHOD and I thought that was the method name. Woops. /

Comment: Shouldn't that be ````var index = require('./index.js') ?
I think I'm missing something here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135767/discussion-between-r-gulbrandsen-and-user3927312).